# The integration of modified bessel function of the second type

Tags: bessel-functions

I need some help to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ x^{\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} - 1} K_{\alpha-\beta} \sqrt {2(\frac{\alpha\beta}{\gamma}x)} dx$$
Where $\alpha, \beta,\gamma, $ are constants and $K_{\alpha-\beta}$
 is the modified bessel function of the second type.